# +/- sign in TimeSpan's ParseExact()?

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

I need to parse a string that specifies the environment's timezone. It looks like `+0100` or `-0530`, specifying the offset from the UTC time zone.

In these strings, the plus/minus sign is **always** there. I want to parse this with the `TimeSpan.ParseExact()` method, and I'm quite sure that there is a way. The `Parse()` method knows how to deal with a minus sign, but [the `ParseExact()` method's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) does not mention anything about signs whatsoever.

So far, the format I'm using is `hhmm`, but this will need to be prefixed by something that deals with the +/- sign. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you write an example of the string ?

Comment: I'm missing what does TimeSpan has to do with TimeZone?

Comment: Those time zone offsets belong to a `DateTime`, not a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: "the ParseExact() method's documentation does not mention anything about signs whatsoever." - except inside the **important** box at the top, where it says "Custom TimeSpan format specifiers also do not include a sign symbol that enables you to differentiate between negative and positive time intervals. To include a sign symbol, you have to construct a format string by using conditional logic."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check if it starts with `-`, then apply the appropriate format string:

```
string[] timespans = { "-0530", "+0100" };
foreach (string timespan in timespans)
{
    bool isNegative = timespan.StartsWith("-");
    string format = isNegative ? "\\-hhmm" : "\\+hhmm";
    TimeSpanStyles tss = isNegative ? TimeSpanStyles.AssumeNegative : TimeSpanStyles.None;
    TimeSpan ts;
    if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timespan, format, null, tss, out ts))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} successfully parsed to: {1}", timespan, ts);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not be parsed: {0}", timespan);
    }
}
```

Note that i use `TimeSpanStyles.AssumeNegative` in `TryParseExact`, otherwise the timespans would be always positive even if they are prepended with a minus.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is not supported. From [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Custom `TimeSpan` format specifiers also **do not include a sign symbol
> that enables you to differentiate between negative and positive time
> intervals**. To include a sign symbol, you have to construct a format
> string by using conditional logic. The [Other Characters section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Other)
> includes an example.

But looks like [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) support this. In [Patterns for Duration values](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/duration-patterns.html) page, it has `+` and `-` as a characters part.

[image]

```
using NodaTime.Text;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DurationPattern pattern = DurationPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("+hhmm");
            TimeSpan timeSpan = pattern.Parse("+0100").Value.ToTimeSpan();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FT9sJM)</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for timezone offsets:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("14-oct-2015 08:22:00 +01:00","dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss zzz", culture);
```

But this only works for DateTime, not TimeSpan, as timezone information is not supported in TimeSpan strings.